# Disable the browser's reflow\redraw

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, reflow

I'm adding quite a few elements to the DOM.  I don't want the browser to attempt to redraw the page until all the elements are added.

Is this possible?

Comment: It probably *won't* redraw after each element. The main thing to be careful with is interspersing DOM addition/removal with queries for things like element sizes and positions, because those queries will force the browser to redraw in order to get you the right answer.

Comment: You can use a [fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) and add your elements to that 'element' and append it when it's finished.

Comment: @Pointy Interesting point about querying sizes.  I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a new element, add all your elements to that element and then finally add that element to the DOM so it only redraws once.

One way to do this without adding an extra intermediate node to the html is to use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

```js
const numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const temp_holder = new DocumentFragment();
  for(let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = i.toString();
    temp_holder.appendChild(li);
  }

  numbers.appendChild(temp_holder);
});
```

```html
<ul id="numbers">
  <li>0</li>
</ul>
<button id="button" type="button">Add numbers</button>
```

Comment: That works if I'm only manipulating one node (and its child nodes).  As it turns out, I am.  It clicked in my head that I'm over complicating everything just before you posted.